# whois lookup limits - how to work around daily quota/query limits

Tags: dns, limit, whois

I'm building a website that allows users to check the availability of international domain names. My approach was to do a simple whois lookup on each request, but I'm now realizing that there are pretty harsh daily or hourly limits, e.g.

> "Allowed average daily response limit is set to 100 regarding one IP address."

Is there a way to work around this issue? How do all these sites offer this kind of service, without running into problems with the query limits?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is not in the programming domain, as is the answer.

WHOIS sites maintain a database of domain information, that is not easy, nor cheap, data to maintain.

You have no (legal) programmatic way to overcome this issue. What I'm sure you can do is work out a plan with a respected WHOIS provider that will give you access to it's data, without quotas, for a periodic fee.

Comment: That's not truth. Sharing WHOIS database as a torrent download costs literally nothing. Just those "noncommercial" entities (registries) decided that they can sell the data for profit.

Answer (score 17):

The reason for the rate limiting by those guys is to charge a premium for a service, not because the infrastructure can't handle actual lookup requests. It's called a business model ;) :p

Answer (score 9):

Polish registry, has limited access to whois to 100 queries a day per IP and there is no way to avoid that. As a workaround, Polish programmers are forced to buy additional IP's. With 200 or 300 IP's, you can query up to 30,000 times a day.